# Using Xcode preferences vs .gitignore file

Tags: xcode, git, gitignore, preferences

I'm new to git repositories and have found lots of great support for creating a .gitignore file that I would put in each project directory.

However, I've noticed that in Xcode 10 preferences under Source Control under the git tab there is a spot to specify files to ignore. Is there an advantage to defining the exclusions in Xcode versus the .gitignore file? I can't seem to find anyone that actually does it this way and Apple docs are light.

Are there some items (maybe globals) that I would put be better putting in prefs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there some items (maybe globals) that I would put be better putting in prefs?

They should *all* be globals. There is probably no reason for you to have individual `.gitignore` files on a project by project basis. The Xcode 10 preferences to which you refer is merely another window onto your global `.gitignore` file. It is, after all, git that is to do the ignoring — not Xcode.

Your question seems to imply that you are not using a global `.gitignore` file. Use one. What I do is maintain this file in my home directory, and call it `.gitglobalignores`. The file is pointed to through the `.gitconfig` file (there's a good explanation of how to arrange that [here](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/)). Whether you type out the file by hand in a text editor or manage it through the Xcode 10 preferences window doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks, I used the link you provided to set up the global file in my home directory and [https://www.gitignore.io] to create the Swift, Xcode ignore content. Now I can see that when I create a new project the unnecessary files are no longer being tracked.

Comment: @matt Thank you for the answer. I just noticed the Git tab in Xcode preferences and wondered why its values doesn't change when switching projects. having one global `.gitignore` file is helpful, but I can see situations where adding a per-repo `.gitignore` file is the better way (e.g. when opening a repo for public collaborators).

Comment: @alobaili The Git tab in Xcode is only the global `gitignore`. Having a per-repo is also fine but you can't manage it in Xcode's preferences. You just manage it like a normal file.