# Using .Gitignore in Xcode Project

Tags: xcode, gitignore

I'm new in using Git and Xcode together, I manually add .gitignore in my every project but sometimes i forget about it, So is there any way to do this automatically for me in case of I forget it?

Comment: AFAIK, Xcode doesn't automatically create a .gitignore file. If you do forget about it, adding it is very simple.

Comment: Just as I thought, thanks anyway.

Comment: @iArmvn You can create a global git ignore file, either in a text editor or from Xcode's Source Control preferences. See the following question: [Using Xcode preferences vs .gitignore file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52906874/using-xcode-preferences-vs-gitignore-file)